# Azure MySQL flexible server showing special characters as codes

Tags: azure, azure-mysql-database

After a new instance of Azure  MySQL flexible server is setup, i imported data from existing mysql data base using Heidi and it looks like all data is imported but after a deeper look , realised that  all the apostrophes, ampersands, etc are now displaying as code on the web page like below

Original text:   ‘Green’ light for world’s first
Azure Mysql text:  â€Greenâ€ light for worldâ€s  first

Checked the following settings on both instance and it  is the same value across all servers

```
 SELECT @@character_set_database, @@collation_database; 
 
 utf8mb4  && utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Is there any other settings need to be verified at time of import

Comment: Have you followed the guidelines in this classic answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through That is about PHP, but the same applies to any language.